# Cannot configure Windows authentication for a ASP.NET MVC5 site

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-authorization

I have a site that uses OWIN authentication. All works perfectly, however, I need to restrict access for this site before placing it to the public.

To accomplish this, I want to make the system to present the windows authentication dialog box before the home page is loaded.

I put this in web.config of the site:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <globalization culture="es-CL" uiCulture="es" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="Demo" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

But the home page does not work.

when I try to load home page, this actual URL is loaded:

```
http://demo.site.cl/Security/Account?ReturnUrl=%2FSecurity%2FAccount%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FSecurity%252FAccount%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FSecurity%25252FAccount%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FSecurity%2525252FAccount%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FSecurity%252525252FAccount%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FSecurity%25252525252FAccount%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FSecurity%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FSecurity%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FSecurity%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FSecurity%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FSecurity%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FSecurity%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FSecurity%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FSecurity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

And a 404 error is shown.

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you show us the authentication method?

Comment: Authentication method is Window